# Porting python program from GTK+2 to GTK+3

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

How can we automate the porting of a python file from GTK+2 to GTK+3 with out manually editing tags. If it's not possible what is the best possible way of porting them?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [porting guide](http://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/porting.html) for porting from PyGTK to PyGObject. It describes a tool which automates part of the work, so you can do *less* manual editing, but not *none*.

There's also a [migration guide](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html) from GTK 2 to GTK 3, describing what usages of the APIs themselves have to change.